# Refreshing data used by a query from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have three sheets, sheet A, B and C.

- Sheet A contains data read from sheet B
- Sheet B contains data read from sheet C.
- Sheet C automatically builds from a big CSV file that updates every hour.
- Sheet B reads parts of the data from sheet C.
- Sheet A is used by external people.

The reason sheet A is not looking up data directly from sheet C is privacy and security reasons, that's why I hop through an intermediary sheet which the users of sheet A do not have edit access to.

Long story short: I actually only need to make sure Sheet B is automatically updating it's data from Sheet C, so Sheet A always looks at fresh data.

**Is there no way to simply load/recalculate a Google Sheet on a schedule?**

I see there are some answers here and there that seem to be ridiculously complicated, like setting up ITTT.com or adding macros that add and remove lines into spreadsheets etc.

Surely there must be an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: having open all 3 shets 24/7 is out of options?

Comment: Welcome. For the sake of clarity... you ask "_there must be an elegant way of doing this?_ One is left with the impression that your system DOES work. Yeah? it sounds as though the @player0 comment re: three sheets open 24/7 is actually the status quo. So when you say "elegant way of doing this", what do you have in mind? I'm asking because you haven't described or explained how Sheet C gets its data nor the trigger for the update, nor how/what data is passed onto sheet B, and then to Sheet A, nor whether you have any scripts running. Please edit your question to provide more detail.